# Transparent graphics surface in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am making an application in VB.NET that allows a user to highlight some text in images of documents so that the highlights could be saved for future reference, but the original images would not be modified. I figured I can achieve it by creating a graphics out of an image file and allowing the user to draw on that graphics. The problem is - the graphics can not be created from indexed image files, which many of mine are. I am wondering: is it possible to create a transparent graphics surface above an image in a PictureBox control, so that the user could draw on that surface, but it would appear as if he is drawing directly on an image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(following assumes WinForms)

---

Actually you can.
To display image, use `.BackgroundImage` property of `PictureBox`, not `.Image`.
Don't forget to set correct value for `.BackgroundImageLayout` to disable default tiling and keep it in sync with `.SizeMode` property, so that overlay image is properly aligned.
After you set image, create an overlay image (assume your `PictureBox` is `PictureBox1`:

```
Dim image = PictureBox1.BackgroundImage
Dim overlay As New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(overlay)
g.Clear(Color.Transparent)
'draw something just to show this is working:'
g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Aqua, New Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height))
g.Dispose()
PictureBox1.Image = overlay
```

Now you can draw on the overlay image.
Alternatively, you can copy your image (draw it to the overlay for example).

Comment: Wow! Just tested it. I do not have words. Simple and elegant. Thank you, Max, very, VERY much!

Comment: Is there a button on this site somewhere, that I can click so that you would get some points?

Comment: You've already done that by accepting this answer as a correct one

Comment: You can also use the up/down arrows on items to give points.  ;-)  Just saying...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It requires me to register though, that I probably will. Tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, SLaks might be right that you can't overlay transparent controls and have that work as expected.

I thought you could avoid this but ... instead make your own control.  Keep track of your highlights and annotations either as a second bitmap or as the original highlight/annotation data (whichever is more appropriate for your purpose).  On Paint, you'll draw the original image and then you'll draw your bitmap (or draw each component of it) onto your control's Graphics surface.

You can do some tweaks to make it more responsive within the GDI+ framework and also within your own code.

Comment: Hi, Jason. The hurdle is I do not quite know how to make a transparent drawing surface over an image. Any help?

Comment: Thank you, Jason. I was thinking about it too, but my images are big and the user will be moving them around a LOT, so I did not quite like the idea, that the paint event would slow down the experience.
I just tried the approach suggested by Max, and it seems working :-)

Comment: That's a fine solution I guess.  It won't scale to additional layers though ... Also, remember that the paint has to occur either way.  GDI+ tells you which sections of the image needs repainting, so you can optimize it.

Comment: This is a great website, and you, guys, are super great!

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need to make draw on a copy of the image and set the PictureBox to display the modified copy.

Comment: Thank you, SLaks, for answering. You are right, that's WinForms.  
That is a pity what you said. I was hoping I could.
Is there a method in VB.NET to convert an indexed image into a "normal" one, so that I could create a graphics out of it?

Comment: Make a new `Bitmap`, then call `DrawImage` to put the old one into it.

Comment: Thank you, SLaks. I tried that, but it seemed a tad slow. I did not quite figure why. May be it's because my images are big and DrawImage is not as fast as Image.FromFile method. I will give it another try.